# Does an ActiveX component run inside the process space of the Active Container?

Tags: activex

Does an ActiveX component always run inside the process space of an Active Container? Or does it run in its own process space or some separate process space and communicate with the calling application through inter-process communication?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX components can be out-of-process (.exe) or in-process (.dll or .ocx)...

quote from MSDN:

Components can run either in-process or out-of-process with respect to the clients that use their objects. An out-of-process component, or ActiveX EXE, runs in its own address space.

more info here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242100(v=vs.60).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242100%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)